# Tracking down my OOM error (Out Of Memory)

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-glide

So I have a few theories on my issue, but I have read some conflicting information that makes my situation a bit confusing for me.

To outline my issue from a top-level view:

I have an app with 3 `Fragments` in a tab-layout.  The first of which (that display's on app load) contains a `RecyclerView`.  Each `ViewHolder` contains a row of one `TextView` and 3 `ImageButtons`, all of which have background textures loaded from small (100-300kb) `.jpg` images stored in the `/drawable-nodpi` folder.  The Image buttons also have an additional small (1kb) `.png` that are displayed on top of these textures.

Between this `RecyclerView` and the `ImageButton`s from the main activity the images total to about 6MB that the app would eventually have to load on start-up.

Respectively, the app works fine on recent APIs, or generally more recent phones.  The app tends to get spotty in the `API 23` and bellow range.  Some `API 23` phones work, however some crash from various reasons.  I realize that there could be a slew of different reasons for each crash, so for this question I'm focusing on the famed `"Out of Memory"` error.  I do have a physical API 23 phone I have been attempting to profile with android studio, and the memory looks something like this:

[image]

So far this supports the idea that at least on this particular phone with API 23, I am having a graphic rendering issue, perhaps image loading?  Although my heap dumps and memory profiling don't work, so I can't get specific running tasks.

**On Image Rendering**
Now this is where I get confused.  Most of the info online in this case points to using a library such as Glide or Picasso or Facebook's own Fresco.  However, I have also seen comments in other related SO posts mentioning for people like me who load images from the Drawables folder don't need to use these libraries.  (especially when my images are quite small compared to those in gallery applications, which can amount to a MB per picture.)

However the overwhelming info online suggests that this can be solved with a library, so my question:  Can it?  Or is my problem elsewhere, perhaps in my fragment code, or my Adapter, etc.

I'll start with my images:

/src/main/res

- drawable/

  - .png's (avg around 1kb, less than 100x100 pixels)  These are the foreground drawables
- drawable-nodpi/

  - .jpg textures (avg 100-300kb, 1200x1500px and 3000x2000px respectively)  Perhaps this is where I can save on memory?

Now I would post my code here, however It seems I don't as my problem is really with my above images, more on that In my followup answer.  I had also gone through and implemented some changes utilizing Glide, but it quickly became a large expedition to migrate my current logic into a different image loading structure.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt at a solution was to switch my image logic into my adapter.  Mind you, these `ImageButtons` were originally loaded via being assigned to the background attribute in the xml layout.  This involved shuffling around some of my model logic attributed to those buttons and passing information back and forth between the Fragment and the Adapter.

This ended up looking something like this:

```java
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
...

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // initialize your data here

        mAdapter = new FooListAdapter(mfooList, getContext()); //<-- Pass Fragment reference
        mfooList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mfooList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }
...
}

public class FooListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BeatListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final RequestManager requestManager;
    private Context context;

    FooListAdapter(List<Foo> fooList, Context context) {
        this.fooList = fooList;
        this.context = context
        this.requestManager = Glide.with(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FooListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // Initialize your views

        requestManager.load(R.Drawable.class.getField("name_" + model.fooId).getInt(null))
            .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable> {
                // override methods here, and set the background
                view.setBackground(resource);
            });

        // listeners

        buttonListener = (View view) -> {
            // change model
            // load new image with Glide
            // update model in fragment
        }

        // Set button listeners
    }
}
```

Although since there is a lot going on with my buttons and the model, this is a big change to my logic structure, and I abandoned this idea as it did not seem to bring immediate results.  I originally had my listeners in my `Fragment`, so they have direct access to the data model.

One down side to having the above logic structure would actually be retaining a reference to the Fragment, and continuously pass information back and forth which isn't very efficient, and possibly could introduce memory leaks later on.

**The Solution**
As I thought about my setup, and did some fruitless tracing and memory profiling, I realized a BIG factor I have been overlooking.

My images may have been relatively small, but 300kb doesn't matter if your images are over 1000 pixels large.  This means when android goes to render your image, it's taking actually quite a large amount of pixels and converting it into a `bitmap`.

This problem is exacerbated by the fact that I place my images in the `nodpi` folder to 'simplify' the image choices by android.  Android is taking my 1000+ images and trying to fit it into a button no more than 200 pixels big... that takes quite a lot of computation.

So I thought i'd try reducing my images to a size more suitable for their intended use, and I was amazed.  My 300kb image sizes were being reduced to 10kb!!! Now that they are more of a correct size, I started up my app without any crashes!

Now on to my other bugs...